# Get the row that doesn't exists on the limited select

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the row items wherein that item should not be existing in the select statement with limited no of rows returned. By the way please no IN statement since the mysql version doesn't support the IN.

Well what exactly I need is to get the top 20 rows of user then if the user exists on that top 20 that should be the final list or else I need to display that user. In order to achieve that I plan to make a two query then use union but didn't know why my query always return zero result where it should return 1 record. Here's my query for getting the record that doesn't exists on top 20:

```
select t.*
from
user t
where t.iduser=39
and not exists (select u.* from user u order by points desc limit 20)
```

I'm expecting to get the whole row for id 39 but returned zero result.

I also tried this query:

```
select t.*
from
(select u.* from user u order by points desc limit 20) u,
user t
where t.iduser <> u.iduser
and t.iduser = 39
```

but still never worked for me. wherein if I changed the id into 11 where the iduser 11 exists on the top 20 and changed the <> into = it returns the row for 11 and not for 39 as expected. I'm getting lost on this.

As requested, okay just for more idea the  `select u.* from user u order by points desc limit 20` returns:
iduser 1-20 with points of 0-19 desc respectively. I have 40 rows where 21-40 has 0 points. I guess that is plain simple. :)

Comment: Do you have access to create a view on this database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because your `not exists` clause is equivalent to `true`. The subquery returns a non-empty result (the top 20 users) all the time.

If you prefer `not exists`, try this:

```
select t.*
from
user t
where t.iduser=39
and not exists (
  select * from (select u.* from user u order by points desc limit 20) x 
  where t.iduser=x.iduser
)
```

A probably faster solution is:

```
select t.*
from
user t
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(select u.* from user u order by points desc limit 20) u
ON t.iduser = u.iduser
where u.iduser IS NULL
and t.iduser = 39
```

Comment: LEFT OUTER JOIN? Your `t` table is restricted to `t.iduser = 39` record only. How will the result show top 20 records if that id does not exist? Your query will always show 0 record or at max 1 record.. Isn't it?

Comment: nope this is good enough. that's the only part I need. :)

Thanks @Xiangpeng Zhao.

Comment: That depends on KaHeL's purpose. If the goal is to test whether a given user is in top 20 or not, then it is definitely unnecessary to use this JOIN. If the goal is to find *all* users that are not in top 20 (i.e. remove `t.iduser=39` then the JOIN method is probably faster (depending on the platform though).

Comment: Purpose is to get record that is not in top 20 then I'll just union all the top 20 record. Which is why the left outer join is the better solution in my case. Once again thanks!